# pointgrey ros node?

Tags: ros, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have anyone used pointgrey camera with ROS?
If so, what rosnode will be good?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67380/pointgrey-ros-node?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-16**:
The answer depends on which camera model you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Hyon, you can take a look at [camera1394stereo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394stereo) node that we use with bumblebee2 cameras from pointgrey.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1